# Update notifcation text

Tags: android, sql, android-intent, notifications, alarm

I have currently setup a small application which sets an alarm on the device and stores relevant information inside of an SQL database e.g. Alarm name and time. When the alarm is activated my application sends a notification to the user. Currently each notification is static which means every message is the same. I would like to now allow my application to grab the name of the alarm which has been activated and display it in the notification. Now I know that when setting multiple alarms you require multiple ID's which I have stored in side of my SQL and I'm guess the same when it comes to sending a notification. Is there a way of matching my Alarms ID with one on a notification so that it knows what message to send e.g. alarm name?

Current code for setting my Alarm

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(view.getContext(), Integer.valueOf(alarm_request_code), receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

intentArrayList.add(pendingIntent);
```

My Broadcast receiver...

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Intent moveActivity = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);


    moveActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, moveActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("Standard text")
            .setContentText("Standard text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true);


    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());



}
```

//////////////

Update on my situation which is slowly driving me crazy

I can now set the text from my SQL to my notification but its only the first from my database each time. Now I've come up with two possible solutions which are only theory's.

1. Is there a way in which each time the database is called to the notification it will move onto the next result?
2. As I mentioned above I'm setting an alarm and when the alarm goes off it then calls the notification. Now In my pending intent for the alarm I'm giving it a id which you can see as alarm_request_code is there a way of giving it to my notification ID and then setting up a statement where if the notification ID is equal to or in the list of my alarm ID's stored on my SQL then it will search for the correct text to input.

   MyDatabaseHandler myDatabaseHandler = new MyDatabaseHandler(context, null, null, 1);

   ```
   Cursor cursor = myDatabaseHandler.getAllProducts();


   // Information we are trying to acquire but can only get first result
   String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alarm_name"));
   String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alarm_date"));

   // Alarm ID FROM SQL which we want to match with the NOTIFICATION ID.....
   String alarm_request_code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alarm_code"));



   ////




   Log.i("The reciever is working", "perfect");

   //create an intent to service

   Intent service_Intent = new Intent(context, MessageService.class);
   context.startService(service_Intent);

   //Notification

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



   Intent moveActivity = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);


   moveActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

   // Works with moveActivity to move the user back to main application.
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, moveActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setContentTitle(name)
           .setContentText(date)
           .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
           .setAutoCancel(true);




   notificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(alarm_request_code), builder.build());



   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update text store `mBuilder` variable
and update later in this way:

`mBuilder.setContentTitle(head);
        mBuilder.setContentText(body);
        mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_ID, mBuilder.build());`

**EDIT**

```
    private void simple() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentIntent(pIntent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_24dp);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(someiconLollipop);
            mBuilder.setColor(somecolorLollipop]);
        }

        noti = mBuilder.build();
//use flags if you need:
        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

to update the text:

```
      private void showText() {
            String head = yournewhead;
String body = yournewbody;

            mBuilder.setContentTitle(head);
            mBuilder.setContentText(body);

            mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks could I have a little more detail please.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer I'm going to try and build on it to apply my SQL database. Thank you

Comment: @Steven , do not forget to approve the answer if you would helpfil

Comment: @Steven , i think the best idea is to create a new one question. Due to they are completely different.

Comment: @Steven , by the way i think the most useful solution is to create a wrapper: SQLite + notification updater.

Comment: @Steven, as I understood you (about the second one), it is workable solution.

Comment: Ok Ill make another question ow

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs you can do the following:

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user

    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

The trick here is your notify id, which must be the same in order to behave appropriately, in your case 0.

So as long it has not been dismissed it should work accordingly. I will suggest having a unique id as a constant for your custom notification such as 123.

```
 notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```